# Can a laplacian-beltrami operator have negative eigenvalues?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, eigenvalues

Is it possible for an Laplace-Beltrami operator for Riemannian manifold to have negative eigenvalues?

If not, are there any non-riemannian manifolds where one may observe negative eigenvalues for heat kernel operator?

Comment: This depends on the context. On a noncompact space, yes, unless you specify a certain function space. For example, cosh is an eigenfunction on $\mathbb R$. It is smooth, but not in $L^p$ for any $p$.

Comment: I see, what about compact spaces? I have a feeling that it might be possible to negative eigenvalues for compact manifolds. Is there any theorm regarding this that you might be aware of?

Comment: The Laplace-Beltrami operator satisfies $\int_Mf\cdot\Delta f\,d\mathrm{vol}=\int_M|df|^2\,d\mathrm{vol}$ on a compact manifold without boundary (the boundary terms in Green's formula vanish if there is no boundary). On compact manifolds with boundary, it depends on the boundary conditions whether there are negative eigenvalues or not.

Comment: In the standard setting of spectral theory that considers $-\Delta$ as an unbounded operator in $L^2(M)$ the spectrum is always nonnegative, regardless of $M$ being compact or not. You can also see from the expression of the solution to the heat equation on $M$ with the spectral resolution $\{E_\lambda \}_\lambda$ of $-\Delta$ that if you had some negative point-wise spectrum then the solutions to the heat equation would tend locally to $\pm \infty$ (based on the sign of the eigenfunction there) as $t\to \infty$, and this clearly does not happen.